# Jaxb unmarshalling stuck threads XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

In the thread dumps analysis, I found that around 25 threads were stuck with the below stacktrace:

```
for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" Id=5986 RUNNABLE
 at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:876)
 at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
 at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(XMLReaderImpl.java:557)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:98)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:895)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:659)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:585)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:140)
 at com.mycomp.hif.host.generic.util.XYZUtility.createObject(XYZUtility.java:90)
```

Does this stack mean that XML validation on prolog is taking time? Or anything else?
Please, any suggestions on how we can improve the performance in JAXB unmarshalling?

Answer (score 0):

This is a WebLogic12c setup. "sjsxp.jar" seems to be an old parser "Sun Java Streaming XML Parser". The issue was resolved after removing the "sjsxp.jar" from the application libraries so an alternative latest parser is picked.